How to hide an enum value from swagger documentation in java
Using java and springdoc-openapi, I'm Currently using an enum like this:

       enum Stage {
                    Stage1, Stage2 Stage3, Stage4 etc..;
            }


For one controller I want to show in the swagger UI all of the values, first as a list that shows the options, and than a dropdown to choose - this is the working case right now.
For another controller, I want to hide one value.
is this behavior possible, and if so how?
I tried using a dto with a custom serializer, to hide the value, but than the swagger ui showed only the first value, as a json without the dropdown menu, probably because it didn't recognize the dto is holding an enum.
Thank you

Firstly Use a standard enum definition for Stage
public enum Stage {
    Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4;
}

Then create a DTO with custom Serializer for where you want to hide one of the enum values.
public class CustomStageSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Stage> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Stage stage, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) 
        throws IOException {
        // Serialize all stages except the one you want to hide
        if (stage != Stage.Stage4) {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(stage.name());
        }
    }
}

Use the @JsonSerialize annotation to apply this serializer to your DTO field.
public class CustomStageDTO {
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomStageSerializer.class)
    @Schema(allowableValues = {"Stage1", "Stage2", "Stage3"})
    private Stage stage;
}

Now use this DTO in your controller whare want to hide enum values.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @PostMapping("/custom-stage")
    public void postCustomStage(@RequestBody CustomStageDTO customStageDTO) {
    }
}

When use this approach will let Swagger recognize the enum type in CustomStageDTO and display only the values specified in the @Schema annotation dropdown, with Stage4 hidden.

Thanks for your replay.
Like I mentioned in the original post, I tried creating a custom serializer with a dto, the issue with this approach was that swagger don't recognize the enum anymore because it's wrapped therefore he's not displaying it in the same way anymore and also only showing the first value.
So this solution doesn't work for me.
